# check if remote image is displayed

Tags: php, image, proxy, filtering

I have a PHP site that allows a user to search for and display images. Images come from a variety of sources and as such, some are blocked by a web filtering service.

Site is aimed at multiple users that will like have different web filtering servicew.

How can I determine if the image is displayed or not?

Have tired `getimagesize()`, `get_headers()`, `file_exists()` with no luck . These functions report the image details correctly (I get a 200 OK response etc.), however the webfiltering then blocks the image from being shown.

My current process is `cURL` the image search request (using Google's image search API), json decode the results and then display images with their remote URL as the src.

I could save all the images to my server for each search request, but that seems too bandwidth intensive.

Comment: try something like this: <img src="image.gif" onerror="imgError('image.gif')"> and imgError(string) should be a function that uses ajax to report to the server that the user didn't see the image

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
<img src="image.gif" onerror="imgError('image.gif')">
```

and imgError(string) should be a function that uses ajax to report to the server that the user didn't see the image